# for cycle doesn't work in my .twig file and fails to show items

Tags: symfony, twig, dql

I'm using this .twig file to show the result of a query:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{{parent()}}
<div class="container">
     
        <div class="col-md-12">
            
                {% for eq in equipos %}
                
                 <div class="row well">
                    <h2>{{ eq.nombre }}</h2>
                    <br>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>{{'CPU'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.cPU }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
        
                        <dt>{{'GPU'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.gPU }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
        
                        <dt>{{'RAM'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.rAM }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
        
                        <dt>{{'HDD'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.hDD }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
        
                        <dt>{{'Placa Base'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.placaBase }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
        
                        <dt>{{'Sistema Operativo'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.sO }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
        
                        <dt>{{'Garantia'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.garantia }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
        
                        <dt>{{'Fecha de Compra'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.fechaCompra }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
                        
                        <dt>{{'Marca del Fabricante'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.marcaFabricante }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
                        
                        <dt>{{'Observaciones'}}</dt>
                        <dd>
                            {{ eq.observaciones }}
                            &nbsp;
                        </dd>
                        <br>
                    </dl>
                </div> 
                
              {% endfor %}
            
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

and this is the function which makes the query:

```
public function equiposverAction($id)
{
    $session = new Session();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    
    $dql = "SELECT e FROM ClientBundle:Equipos e where e.idclient=$id";
    
    $equipos = $em->createQuery($dql);
    
    return $this->render('ClientBundle:Client:equiposver.html.twig',array('name'=>$session->get('name'), 'equipos'=>$equipos));
    
}
```

What happens is that the for cycle can't process the query for unknown reasons, even if I write something inside, it doesn't shows a certain number of times, and it should repeat three times because this query shows 3 results. I used the same method in other .twig files on my app, but I'm having this problem only here.

Comment: Hell. So query injection is still possible this way :(

Answer (score 1):

what about getting some results from your query :)

```
$equipos = $em->createQuery($dql)->getResult();
```